# TINYINT wrongly converted to NULL instead of boolean in doctrine / symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

This is the craziest thing I ever seen.
My Symfony2 and Doctrine has gone mad

I have MySQL database with few different fields that are TINYINT. 
Those are not nullable and all records have those values set to 0 or 1.

All doctrine ORM mapping ale set correctly (I doublechecked it hundred times).
All getters are set correctly (doublechecked as well).

But then - for **some** objects it doesn't work ... some of the TINYINT are not correctly translated to BOOLEAN as it should (and as it works with other objects and with other fields of that enity)... instead it gives NULL - even if in database this TINYINT is set to "1" (or "0" - it doesn't matter).

For some other objects (of the same entity) it works fine TINYINT = "1" is correctly recognized as true and "0" as false boolean.

Those my examples:

Events.orm.xml:

```
  <entity name="Events" table="events">
    <change-tracking-policy>DEFERRED_IMPLICIT</change-tracking-policy>
    <field name="eventDeleted" type="boolean" column="_event_deleted"/>
```

Entity: "Events.php"

the mapping:

```
/**
 * @var boolean $eventDeleted
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="_event_deleted", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $eventDeleted;
```

and getter and setter:

```
/**
 * Set eventDeleted
 *
 * @param boolean $eventDeleted
 */
public function setEventDeleted($eventDeleted)
{
    $this->eventDeleted = $eventDeleted;
}

/**
 * Get eventDeleted
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getEventDeleted()
{
    return $this->eventDeleted;
}
```

The database is:

[image: database view]

And as I said - for some objects it works and gives "1" or "0" when accessed by for example:

```
{{ event[0].getEventDeleted }}
```

and sometimes it gives NULL.

I found some "similar" issue mentioned in doctrine jira, but no guess what solves that and what could be the reason: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1967

Any idea?

Comment: Did you check somewhere (Symfony2 Profiler, manual dump) what data gets  into actual queries? If your stack has gone mad, you're better off with just following the rabbit, maybe you've even found a bug in Doctrine2?

Comment: I did checked dump. Everything works as we could expect from the description - in those cases I mentioned "null" is passed. But why?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the query "by hand" with the query builder.
I also had the same problem on symfony 2.1 while fetching an entity from the session variable, a boolean field was returning null no matter what value it had. Using the query builder made it work for me.

**EDIT**
Example:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();  
$query = $qb->select('e.eventDeleted')  
    ->from('BundleName:Events', 'e')  
    ->where('e.id = :id')  
    ->setParameter('id', $id)  
    ->getQuery();  
$eventDeleted = $query->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Oh, thanks codeforlife, it is nice to hear someone else had the same issue. Actually the question was troubling me in 2014 and earlier, project is currently abandoned, but hey, it is nice you shared your thoughts! I really appreciate that. Could you post an example code you used for handling that null issue in QueryBuilder by hand? :) Thanks in advance.